# How to Get Specific Row Value From CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv, foreach, row

I have a vertical CSV file that looks like this:

```
name,value
case,"123Case0001"
custodian,"Doe_John"
PDate,"10/30/2013"
```

I can read the file like this:

```
CSV.foreach("#{batch_File_Dir_cdata}", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true) do |record|
ev_info = record[0]
ev_val = record[1]
```

The problem is, I need to get a specific `ev_val` for just one specific `ev_info`.  I could potentially use the row number, but foresight tells me that this could change.  What will be the same is the name of information.  I want to find the row with the specific information name and get that value.

When I do the `foreach`, it gets that value and then goes past it and leaves me with an empty variable, because it went on to the other rows.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This isn't a CSV file. CSV are not "vertical", they're "horizontal". How many rows constitute a record, just four?

Comment: it is a csv because there are comma delimited values.  It is just not a traditional csv.

Comment: besides that shouldn't matter.  If the csv had firstname,lastname and I just wanted the last name value for the row where the first name was "Steve", would that be possible?  It is the same issue here.

Comment: I appreciate all the attempts at an answer, but none of them have worked.  I am still stuck.  These comments make it hard to see that I don't have an answer, so I wanted to make sure everyone knew I'm still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of choices, but the easiest is to assign to a variable based on the contents, as in:

```
ev_info = record[0]
ev_val = record[1] if ev_info='special name'
```

Note, though, that you need to define whatever variable you are assigning to outside of the block as it will otherwise be created as a local variable and be inaccessible to you afterwards.

Alternatively, you can read in the entire array and then select the record you're interested in with `index` or `select`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but that didn't work.

CSV.foreach("#{batch_File_Dir_cdata}", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true) do |record|
ev_info = record[0]
b_val = record[1] if ev_info == "Batch"
end
puts "#{b_val} is batch name"

I get error "NameError: undefined local variable or method `b_val' for main:Object" I don't understand how this will help because it is looping through the csv. This row of the csv is in the middle, so by the time it finishes the foreach, I am not at the row where the first column is the one I need.
Unless I am getting this wrong.

Comment: This technique allows you to extract/retain whatever information you want from the row. In the example I gave, it only extracts/retains `record[1]`, but you can extract/retain whatever you want, including the entire record. As for the error you're getting, you have a typo in your transcription of the code I posted. You have `b_val = ...` where I had `ev_val = ...`.

Comment: It's not a typo, I changed it.  I was consistent.  If I kept it ev_val it still doesn't work.

Comment: CSV.foreach("#{batch_File_Dir_cdata}", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true) do |record| ev_info = record[0] b_val = record[1] if ev_info == "Batch" end puts "#{b_val} is batch name

Comment: I get told that the ev_val/b_val is an unnamed variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full code and the error message you're getting. You can't effectively share Ruby code with newlines in comments. If you do share Ruby code in comments, use the backtick operator to quote the code and use semicolons as statement separators where you would otherwise use newlines.

Comment: Sorry, see updated answer. I should have pointed this out initially.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it something like:

```
require 'pp'
require 'csv'

ROWS_IN_RECORD = 4

data = []
File.open('test.dat', 'r') do |fi|
  loop do
    record = {}
    ROWS_IN_RECORD.times do
      row = fi.readline.parse_csv
      record[row.first] = row.last
    end
    data << record
    break if fi.eof?
  end
end

pp data
```

Running that outputs:

```
[{"name"=>"value",
  "case"=>"123Case0001",
  "custodian"=>"Doe_John",
  "PDate"=>"10/30/2013"},
 {"name"=>"value_2",
  "case"=>"123Case0001 2",
  "custodian"=>"Doe_John 2",
  "PDate"=>"10/30/2013 2"}]
```

It returns an array of hashes, so each hash is the record you'd normally get from CSV if the file was a normal CSV file.

There are other ways of breaking down the input file into logical groups, but this is scalable, with a minor change, to work on huge data files. For a huge file just process each record at the end of the loop instead of pushing it onto the `data` variable.

Comment: but I only want 1 value.  So lets look at the data.  It has what you list in that first hash.  I only want to grab the value "Doe_John".  So I need to find the row, where the first column value is "Custodian".  That has the value I need, which is "Doe_John".  How do I say - just give me the value from the line where the name is X?

Comment: The data format you're working with is designed to move data between spreadsheets or with a little massaging, to databases. While it's possible to index into an array created by reading the file, your best solution is to pull it into a database, even a small one like SQLite. In the code above, if you want to access a particular record you use simple array indexing and a hash access: `data[0]['custodian']` would return "Doe_John". However, again, that is a poor way to process a file like this. I'd highly recommend looking into a database if your file is anything above trivial-sized.

Comment: That's just in a different direction than this process. We actually spit out these csvs and need to push them through this process where the script looks in a folder.  It checks for these csv's and for each of them, it reads them, uses certain rows to set the characteristics of each "batch" and then uses the rest of the info to set up metadata values for the batch.  I really want to just understand how to search the csv for the value I want in the row I want, instead of trying to reinvent the process.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.  I original had the following:

```
CSV.foreach("#{batch_File_Dir_cdata}", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true) do |record|
    ev_info = record[0]
    c_val = record[1]
case when ev_info == "Custodian"
 cust = cval
  end
    end
puts cust
```

what I needed to do was this:

```
CSV.foreach("#{batch_File_Dir_cdata}", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true) do |record|
    ev_info = record[0]
    case when ev_info == "Custodian"
    c_val = record[1]
  end
    end

puts c_val
```